# Contribute on GitHub using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I'm not new to using GitHub on Android Studio, but:

This is my first try to contribute to a sample project for Android on GitHub.

I did the following

1. I cloned the repository:

[image: Android Studio UI]

1. I made my changes
2. I committed my changes

[image]

3. I pushed my commit

And baam (here is the problem):

[image]

Why? What things did I miss?

(Don't forget, I have never contributed on GitHub, and this is my first time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to do a contribution:

1. You must fork the repository
2. Clone your fork version of that repository
3. Through the command line, navigate to your clone directory then add upstream version (original repository):

   ```
   $ git remote add upstream https://github.com/fcannizzaro/material-stepper.git
   ```

   You can check it using the line `$ git remote`, and you will see `origin` and `upstream`.
4. Make changes → commit them → then push (all of this happen on your repository (forked one), not the upstream).
5. Go and check the network graph for both the forked and original repositories.
6. Go to the GitHub original repository's link and click `pull request`.
7. Do as described in this image:
   [image]
8. And fill the others field and click *Create pull request*
   [image]

Thanks for [Erik Carlsten's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlNpLMtnWblDyU14hzp40Fa6ZKDJ9UJsJ).

Answer (score 2):

403 indicates that you are not allowed to access the resource - you aren't authenticated with GitHub. To fix this, you should change your remote URL to a repository you have access to, then push your changes:

```
https://myusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```

From the command line you would need to do the following (Android Studio should automatically detect the changes):

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://myusername@github.com/user/repo.git
git push -u origin --all // prompts for authentication, pushes your changes to github
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio, I guess if you try to push your changes through command line you'll get the same result. Read about [Contributing to Open Source on GitHub](https://guides.github.com/activities/contributing-to-open-source/).